# formik change elements on checkbox change

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using formik.
I have a checkbox that says all day event.
if the all day event is selected I want to show a date picker without the time component.

if the all day event is not selected the datepicker has a time component.

this is working properly when the form loads but when I toggle the checkbox the datepicker does not change.

```
 <Formik enableReinitialize
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
           initialValues={activity}
           onSubmit={values => handleFormSubmit(values)}>

            {({ handleSubmit, isValid, isSubmitting, dirty }) => (
                <Form className='ui form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
                <MyCheckBox name='allDayEvent' label='All Day Event' />
                {!activity.allDayEvent && 
                <MyDateInput
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        placeholderText='Start Date / Time'
                        name='start'
                        showTimeSelect
                        timeCaption='time'
                        dateFormat='MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa'
                        title='*Start'  />
                }
               {activity.allDayEvent && 
                <MyDateInput
                        placeholderText='Start Date'
                        name='start'
                        dateFormat='MMMM d, yyyy'
                        title='*Start'  />
                }
         <Button
                disabled ={isSubmitting || !isValid || !dirty}
                 loading={isSubmitting} floated='right' positive type='submit' content='Submit'/>
                <Button as={Link} to='/activities' floated='right'  type='button' content='Cancel'
                />
            </Form>

            )}

          </Formik>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activity` is what you're using for the *initial* values, it's static and does not change (unless you're manually changing it somehow).

Instead, use `values.allDayEvent`, which is the current state of the field in the Formik state.

```
{!values.allDayEvent && 
                <MyDateInput
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        placeholderText='Start Date / Time'
                        name='start'
                        showTimeSelect
                        timeCaption='time'
                        dateFormat='MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa'
                        title='*Start'  />
}
```

Comment: thanks however I am receiving can not find name values.  do I need to add something?

Comment: never mind I found it, I  just had to add values after  handleSubmit, isValid, isSubmitting, dirty it is working now.

Comment: Ah, I thought I saw it. It's one of the formik fields, you just need to include it. Add it to `{({ handleSubmit, isValid, isSubmitting, dirty }) =>`, like `{({ handleSubmit, isValid, isSubmitting, dirty, values }) =>`

Comment: @BryanDellinger beat me to it! Formik takes some getting used to, but I really like it, it's very powerful.